# exclude overlapping shape and text

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

It is possible to exclude overlapping svg shape and text in `HTML` / `CSS` / `JavaScript` ? Any idea?

Example with "ribbon" and "bakery" text :
https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/66994201/disp/90d7a47db61c202f0eb668df22115268.jpg

Comment: Set the color of the text as transparent..in CSS

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi That would make the text invisible, as opposed to "cut out" the background...

Comment: JS or HTML won't really help you here. There is decent support for SVG in browsers nowadays, though! If you're looking for webkit-only solution, look at https://www.webkit.org/blog/164/background-clip-text/

Comment: @xec ya .. bt you can try using text shadow or text outline properties..Im not sure about the browser compatibility though

Comment: I think your easiest cross-browser option is `.png` with a transparent cut out...